# Trying to use list comprehension to convert a string into list. But the code return a generator value instead of output

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
a='sadfaad' 
b=[] 
b.append(x for x in a) 
print(b)
```

It returns
`[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000002042A1DA5F0>]`
What to know why it happens so? and how can we use list comprehension for it?

Comment: Your code appends a generator object to list `b`. What did you expect to see as the output of `print(b)`?

Comment: I think you wanted `b=[x for x in a]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the actual result of the comprehension, you need to exhaust the generator by converting to list:

```
a='sadfaad' 
b=[] 
b.append([x for x in a]) 
print(b)
```

output: `[['s', 'a', 'd', 'f', 'a', 'a', 'd']]`

If you want to add the elements, use `extend`:

```
a='sadfaad' 
b=[] 
b.extend([x for x in a]) 
print(b)
```

output: `['s', 'a', 'd', 'f', 'a', 'a', 'd']`

But, unless this is just a toy example, the best remains to convert without loop:

```
b = list(a)
print(b)
```

output: `['s', 'a', 'd', 'f', 'a', 'a', 'd']`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a simple list comprehension like this:

```
a='sadfaad' 
b = [x for x in a]
```

And that will return a list of characters in a

Answer (score 0):

```
(x for x in a) # This will produce a generator that will yield x when called. Note '()' syntax
[x for x in a] # This will produce a list. Note the '[]' syntax
```

In fact, [x for x in a] can be thought of as a generator expression wrapped in a list constructor.
[x for x in a]  is really the same as list(x for x in a)